# Getting KML of external boundary of several areas from GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have a GeoServer with PostGIS database.

PostGIS database has a table with small geographic areas (English LSOAs and output areas, to be precise), with codes and shapes.

I want to submit to GeoServer a list of area codes, and receive KML of their external boundary. The areas will be conterminous in most cases (not always).
GeoServer should merge the areas and dissolve the inner boundaries where possible.

I figured out how to do it in PostGIS:

```
SELECT ST_askml(ST_Union(ST_SnapToGrid(geom,0.0001)) )
   FROM geo_area
   where identifier = ANY( regexp_split_to_array('E01031338,E01031376,E01031377', ',') )
   group by level_identifier;
```

How do I pass this request to PostGIS via GeoServer?

I guess it can be made by a chain of WPS jobs

> [my_geoserver_url]/geoserver/web/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.wps.web.WPSRequestBuilder

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/wps/install.html

but I am not sure yet.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a parametric SQL view, you can share the load between GeoServer, building the KML in a WMS request, and PostGIS, doing the processing:
https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html